# Generalized Eigenspaces of Composed Operators

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, generalized-eigenvector

I am looking for a proof check, as well as a bit of help.

Let $X$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $R$ and $S$ be linear operators on $X$.

(a) Prove that $SR$ and $RS$ have the same set of nonzero eigenvalues.

(b) Let $\lambda$ be a nonzero eigenvalue of $SR$. Let $U$ be the generalized eigenspace of $SR$ corresponding to $\lambda$. Let $W$ be the generalized eigenspace of $RS$ corresponding to $\lambda$. Show that $S$ maps $U$ into $W$ injectively.

(a) Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $SR$. There are two cases. If $\lambda \neq 0$, let $x$ be an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$. Now $SRx = \lambda x$. Since $\lambda \neq 0$, $Rx \neq 0$, so $RS(Rx) = R\lambda x = \lambda R(x)$. So $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $RS$ as well.

Suppose instead that $\lambda = 0$. Then, by the Invertible Matrix Theorem, $\det(SR) = 0$. But, $\det(SR) = \det(RS) = 0$, so $RS$ is also not invertible, hence it has 0 as an eigenvalue as well.

I would appreciate any corrections or feedback for part (a). For part (b), I am not sure how to proceed. I am aware that if $v \in U$, it can be written as a unique linear combination of generalized eigenvectors of $SR$, then I'm trying to show that the image of such vectors under $S$ are in $W$, but I'm not quite sure how to show this, let alone that this is an injective mapping.

Comment: you sure its "$S$ maps $U$ into $W$" and not "$R$ maps $U$ into $W$?" The latter is significantly easier to prove.

Comment: Yes it is "Show that $S$ maps $U$ into $W$ injectively."

Comment: If we just let $R$ be the identity then $U$ and $W$ are equal, if we let $S,R: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$, and $S$ be the projection from $e_2 \to e_1$ (i.e. projection onto the $x$ axis), then both $U,W$ are $\mathbb R^2$ and $SR=RS=S$ and $S$ is certainly not injective on $U$. I don't think the problem is true as stated.

Comment: The problem states that $\lambda \neq 0$. The matrix of the operator you are referring too  (assuming I am interpreting your comment correctly) is,

\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0\\1&0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

which only has 0 as an eigenvalue. Also, the problem states that the operator is on a complex vector space.

Comment: (a) explicitly ask for non-zero $\lambda$ so you don't need your determinant argument.  A somewhat better approach to (a) is to write $\big(SR-\lambda I\big)\mathbf x =\mathbf 0\implies \big(RS-\lambda I\big)R\mathbf x= R\big(SR-\lambda I\big)\mathbf x =\mathbf 0$ which should prompt you to generalize this with induction to prove $\big(SR-\lambda I\big)^n\mathbf x =\mathbf 0\implies \big(RS-\lambda I\big)^n R\mathbf x= R\big(SR-\lambda I\big)^n\mathbf x =\mathbf 0$, then think about what this has to do with (b)

Comment: @user8675309 Thus, $R$ maps $U$ to $W$. For completion, if $Rx=0$ then by $(SR-\lambda I)^n x = 0$, $x=0$ follows. To see this, in the expansion of $(SR-\lambda I)^n$, the only term without the rightmost $R$, is $(-\lambda I)^n$. Thus, $Rx=0$ will annihilate all terms except $(-\lambda I)^n x$. Hence, we have $x=0$.