If rank($AB$) = rank($BA$) and $AB$ is idempotent then $BA$ is also idempotent.
I came across this question on Quora.

Considering the matrices $A$, $B$ $\in$ $M_n(\mathbb C)$ such that $\text{rank}(AB) = \text{rank}(BA)$. How do I show that $(AB)^2=AB\iff (BA)^2=BA$?

My attempt:
I think it's enough to show that $(AB)^2=AB \implies (BA)^2=BA $ due to symmetry.
It's given that $x(x-1)$ annihilates $AB$. By some algebraic manipulations, it's easy to see that $x^2(x-1)$ annihilates $BA$. Thus, eigenvalues of $BA$ are $1$'s and/or $0$'s. To show that $BA$ is idempotent, it would be enough to show that $\mathbb C^n = \ker(BA)\oplus \ker(I-BA)$ i.e., $\begin{align}\dim\ker (I-BA)&= n-\dim \ker(BA)\\&=\text{rank}(BA)\\&=\text{rank}(AB)\\&=\dim\ker(I-AB).\end{align}\tag*{}$
On the last step, I've used: $\mathbb C^n=\ker(AB)\oplus\ker(I-AB)$ (which is a consequence of idempotence of $AB$).
So if I can show that $\dim\ker(I-AB)=\dim\ker(I-BA),\tag*{}$ I'll be done. I am not sure how to show this. I would also want to see different approaches to this problem. I believe there should be much simpler solution to this than what I'm trying.

Update: I'm able to show that $\dim \ker(AB-I)\leq \dim \ker(BA-I)$ by an injective linear map $\varphi:\,\ker(AB-I)\to\ker(BA-I)$ given by $\varphi(v)= Bv$. It's well defined since we have $\begin{align}&v\in\ker(AB-I)\\&\implies (AB-I)v=0\\&\implies (BAB-B)v=0\\&\implies (BA-I)Bv=0\\&\implies Bv\in\ker(BA-I)\end{align}\tag*{}$
For injectivity, suppose $0\neq v\in\ker\varphi$ then $Bv=0$ and hence, $v\in\ker B\subseteq \ker(AB)$. Again, $v\in\ker(AB-I)$. We see that $v$ is an eigenvector of $AB$ w.r.t. both $1$ and $0$. Contradiction! Thus, $\ker\varphi=\{0\}$. However, I am unable to establish whether $\varphi$ is surjective.

See $\mathrm{rank}(I+AB)=\mathrm{rank}(I+BA)$

also $AB =(AB)^2\implies \text{rank}(AB) = \text{rank}(ABAB)\leq \text{rank}(ABA)\leq \text{rank}(AB)$ and you know $\text{rank}(AB)=\text{rank}(BA)$ so $AB$ and $BA$ are similar https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4083345/a-b-are-complex-matrices-in-mn-mathbbc-and-rankab-rankba-rank/

as far as your Update goes, you should be able to directly argue $\dim \ker (AB-I)=\dim\ker (AB-I)^n = \dim\ker (BA-I)^n$ and $\dim \ker (BA-I)\leq\dim \ker (BA-I)^n$ giving the result

@user8675309 In general, AB and BA have the same JCF ignoring the blocks dedicated to zero. Is that right?

That is explicitly addressed in my answer in the preceding link (via a link near the end of it).  If you prefer to get more in the weeds of the JCF: you can also develop it by pushing your update technique, for $\lambda \neq 0$ argue $\dim \ker \big(AB- \lambda I\big)^k=\dim \ker \big(BA- \lambda I\big)^k$ [left multiplying by $B$ gives an injection one way and left multiplying by $A$ gives an injection the other way] ala https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4836736/generalized-eigenspaces-of-composed-operators

@user8675309 I compiled here everything I understood from your answer. Thank you, I learned a lot!
